# Getting value out of an multidimensional array laravel

Tags: php, laravel

ive currently made a multidimensional array by pushing data in $temp and pushing temp in $fullcursus but i have no clue how to display a specific piece of data

```
public function index()
    {
      $soortcursus =soortcursus::all();
       $cursussen = cursussen::all();
       $fullcursus = array();
foreach ($soortcursus as $soort) {
    foreach ($cursussen as $cursus) {
        if ($soort->soortcode == $cursus->soortcode) {
            $temp = array("cursuscode"=>$cursus->cursuscode,"begindatum"=>$cursus->begindatum,"einddatum"=>$cursus->einddatum,"soortcode"=>$cursus->soortcode,"cursussoort"=>$soort->cursussoort,"prijs"=>$soort->prijs);
           // array_push($fullcursus, $cursus->cursuscode,$cursus->begindatum,$cursus->einddatum,$cursus->soortcode,$soort->cursussoort,$soort->prijs);
        array_push($fullcursus,$temp);
        }
    }
}



       //foreach ($cursuslink as $link) {
       //  array_push($cursussen, cursussen::where('cursuscode',[$link->cursuscode])->get());
     // }

      return view('medewerker_overzicht_cursussen',['cursussen' => $fullcursus]);

    }
```

a vardump of $fullcursus shows:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(6) { ["cursuscode"]=> int(1) ["begindatum"]=> string(10) "2014-06-01" ["einddatum"]=> string(10) "2014-06-08" ["soortcode"]=> int(1) ["cursussoort"]=> string(15) "Beginnerscursus" ["prijs"]=> string(6) "500.00" } [1]=> array(6) { ["cursuscode"]=> int(2) ["begindatum"]=> string(10) "2014-06-08" ["einddatum"]=> string(10) "2014-06-15" ["soortcode"]=> int(1) ["cursussoort"]=> string(15) "Beginnerscursus" ["prijs"]=> string(6) "500.00" } [2]=> array(6) { ["cursuscode"]=> int(3) ["begindatum"]=> string(10) "2014-06-08" ["einddatum"]=> string(10) "2014-06-15" ["soortcode"]=> int(3) ["cursussoort"]=> string(8) "Wadtocht" ["prijs"]=> string(6) "800.00" } }
```

Comment: what do you want to do? Question is unclear

Comment: i editted it , im trying to get  a specific piece of data out of it

Answer (score 0):

Now you have an array. As it is an array now you may do this:

```
foreach ($fullcursus as $cursus) {
     echo $cursus['cursuscode'];
}
```

If you don't want to use `foreach` you must use the array key first. As like:

```
echo $cursus[0]['cursuscode'];
```

**At last:**

What you did here is a bad practice. If there is a relation with soortcursus's soortcode column with cursussen's soortcode you should create a [Laravel's Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships) here.